# What does Eclipse/Java call your homedir?  Since ~ and $HOME does not work

Tags: unix, eclipse, path

When you install Eclipse he always ask me where to put the workspace and here I noticed that Eclipse do not understand normal unix stuff like `~` or `$HOME`.

What does Eclipse/Java call your homedir?

The reason for this question is that I was writing a small installation guide, 
And it seems silly to put my own users home dir in a general guide 
With a confusing text about use your own username.

It would be much nicer (and less confusing) to simply write. Use: `~/workspace`

Is there an Eclipse version of `~` or `$HOME`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java developers might know the `user.home` [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()). I'm not sure how you'd but that into a screenshot though, but the terminology alone might be enough.

As an abstract example, `/home/johndoe` or something along these lines would probably work. But you need to consider that the path to the home directory is very different among the popular OSes: `/home/username`, `/Users/username`, `C:\Users\username` and `C:\Documents and Settings\username` are all common and possibly used by your audience.

But right now it does not apply to Eclipse, since they have not implemented this feature.

Comment: A good idea but eclipse creates user.home as a dir where eclipse was started.

Comment: For this guide I don't need to think about the windows users since windows is not allowed in this project. If someone has windows they must install the correct stuff in a virtual machine. So it is good enough if if works on the unix/linux based systems.

Comment: @johan it's a system property, not a magically translated value. You can use it like I did, in your accompanying explanation. And not all unixes store their user profile data in `/home`. You can't do better than an example.

Comment: You are right and that is why I usually use ~ since then you can have your "home" in whatever dir you like, and from documentation point of view we don't care. It is just a dir where the user are allowed to save files.

Comment: Btw if the system properties don't "automatic translates" how do I use them from a input box as eclipse would like me to do?

Comment: @Johan *You don't*. Just explain that the user should use a path in your workspace. There is no generally working, user name independent symbol or synonym for a user's home directory. You can only explain it in terms your users understand.

Comment: Eclipse uses `@user.home` internally to refer to the user home directory, but that doesn't work either when entered.

Comment: that is kind of primitive, but I guess there is no shortcut.